# How to make a loop in XML Macro

Tags: xml

Im very noob or beginner when it comes to XML. One part of our job is to do a macro scripting in ZHOD or IBM Host on Demand. This is what it actually looks like

[Macro ZHOD screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNWnx.png)

Its supposed to do a copy and paste. Now my question is,  do you know how to do a loop? I want the macro to run again continuously or in cycle. I'm very sorry i just need some help to make our work easier rather than doing a multiple copy and paste. Our go-to guy already resigned so we have no one to ask about this.

Here is the sample of the codes

```
<screen name="Screen1" entryscreen="true" exitscreen="false" transient="false">

    <description >

        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />

        <numfields number="43" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />

        <numinputfields number="4" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />

    </description>

    <actions>

        <input value="[paste]" row="0" col="0" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />

        <input value="683682083D885CD1D160661154B83ED1" row="0" col="0" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="true" enhancedEncryption="true" />

    </actions>

    <nextscreens timeout="10000" >

        <nextscreen name="Screen2" />

    </nextscreens>

</screen>



<screen name="Screen2" entryscreen="false" exitscreen="true" transient="false">

    <description >

        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />

        <numfields number="131" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />

        <numinputfields number="12" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />

    </description>

    <actions>

        <input value="0000019[tab]T410119[enter][enter][pf17][enter][pf5][reset][clear]" row="0" col="0" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />

    </actions>

    <nextscreens timeout="1000" >

        <nextscreen name="Screen1" />

    </nextscreens>

</screen>
```

I believe it is an XML language, appreciate your kind assistance on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to copy data from Excel to IBM Iseries is to use VBA in Excel file to create XML macro (including data) and then run the macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info on this syntax at:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXKAY_9.6.0/com.ibm.hats.doc/mr_reference_to_elements.htm#mr_reference_to_elements

There are some sparse examples on that website.  It uses XML scripting style. I'm learning it myself.

I believe this is the list of syntax.

Encloses all the other elements in the script.
                   Container for  elements.
                     Declares an imported data type (Java class).
                     Container for  elements.
                   Creates and initializes a variable.
                   Screen element, contains info about one macro screen.
              Container for descriptors.
                   Describes a particular field attribute.
                   Describes the location of the cursor.
               Refers to a custom recognition element.
                Describes the number of fields in the screen.
           Describes the number of input fields in the screen.
                   Describes a character string on the screen.
                Assigns a value to a variable.
                  Container for actions.
                 Waits for the specified communication status to occur.
                   Calls a custom action.
                  Copies data from the host application screen.
                     Allows you to insert an else-condition.
                       Allows you to insert an if-condition.
                    Sends keystrokes to the host application.
               Simulates a mouse click.
                    Waits for the specified amount of time.
                  Calls a Java method that you provide.
                Calls another macro.
                   Prompts the user for information.
                    Writes out a trace record.
                 Sends an SQL statement to a host database, retrieves 
                           data, and writes it or displays it. 
                Assigns a value to a variable.
                 Container for  elements.
                  Contains the name of a valid next macro screen.
                   Takes action if recognition limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to use multiple inputs in a HATS / Host on Demand Macro.

1. Separate them into different inputs
2. Create multiple screens with recognition logic for each [command] (with the exception of tabs)
3. Never use "number of fields" in your screen reco logic
4. Don't use "timeout" in the nextscreens field with a value other than "0" (unless you know what you're doing)
5. Next screens is checked in the order they are defined

For creating loops, create a new screen definition called StartLoop, create a LoopScreen and an EndLoopScreen. Change the "nextscreens" order to first check of "EndLoopScreen" then "LoopScreen".